# JWT authentication returns 401 when policy is set in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to add multiple ways to authenticate users in our app. All but one are working flawlessly. I am able to log in with ASP.NET Core Identity, GitHub, Azure AD, and even [API auth](https://github.com/mihirdilip/aspnetcore-authentication-apikey), but JWT is giving me a bit of a headache as I always get a 401 response when I pass in an bearer token to the authorization header.

This might have something to do with a custom middleware class that works on this header:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<JwtAuthMiddleware>()
  .UseAuthentication()
  .UseAuthorization()
```

The middleware class in question:

```
public class JwtAuthMiddleware
{
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

  public JwtAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
  {
    _next = next;
  }

  public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
  {
    string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    if (authHeader != null)
    {
      string jwtEncodedString = authHeader[7..]; // Fetch token without Bearer
      JwtSecurityToken token = new(jwtEncodedString: jwtEncodedString);
      ClaimsIdentity identity = new(token.Claims, "jwt");
      context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    }

    return _next(context);
  }
}
```

The identity setup is fairly simple.

```
services
  .AddAuthentication()
  .AddCookie(/*config*/)
  .AddGitHub(/*config*/)
  .AddJwtBearer(/*config*/)
  .AddAzureAd(/*config*/);

string[] authSchemes = new string[]
{
  IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
  CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
  GitHubAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
  JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
  "InHeader"
};

AuthorizationPolicy authnPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(authSchemes)
.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
.Build();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.FallbackPolicy = authnPolicy;
});
```

I also set a filter in AddMvc:

```
.AddMvc(options =>
 {   
  AuthorizationPolicy policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(authSchemes)
  .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
  .Build();

  options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
```

JWT works when `options.FallbackPolicy` is not set. Otherwise, I get a 401 response. Inspecting the `DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement` in debug mode confirms this as there is no principal set with the right claims filled out. So it looks like `context.User` is ignored or reset.

Ideally, I would want to get rid of `JwtAuthMiddleware` altogether, but I still have to figure out how to combine JWT with cookie authentication in this particular setup. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please see my answer below, I hope that solves your problem. Also, I found this question via a link you posted on another platform. I replied to your question there as well, please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shazad Hassan made some good points in his answer. The custom middleware was in fact not necessary in the end because the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.XXXX` assemblies were throwing errors that the tokens were invalid. I never really knew the token was invalid because the middleware assumed it was correct (and content-wise, it was), while all this time the context was running for an unauthenticated user, which became apparent when I applied the fallback policy.

So I rewrote the token generation code and now I no longer get this issue, and I can safely remove the custom middleware. So far so good.

While I still have to bone up on authentication schemes and all that, for the moment it doesn't even seem necessary to have multiple calls to `AddAuthentication` because this works:

```cs
services
 .AddAuthentication()
 .AddCookie(configureCookieAuthOptions)
 .AddGitHub(configureGithub)
 .AddAzureAd(config)
 .AddJwtBearer(configureJwtBearerOptions)
 .AddApiKeyInHeader<ApiKeyProvider>("InHeader", options =>
  {
    options.Realm = "My realm";
    options.KeyName = "X-API-KEY";
  });
```

With this, I am able to log in with every method in the list. Looks promising, but might need to be reviewed by someone who knows the ins and outs of authentication in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: The above approach will work from the authentication point of view. However, in a scenario where you need to retrieve the claims e.g. AzureAd or Jwt, and you authorize based on the claims, you would get problems. As your `HttpContext.User` would be set to the `ClaimsPrincipal` of the first authentication mechanism able to handle the request.

Comment: In your example, the Authorization policy is only checking if the user is authenticated or not, and because your Jwt token or Key is valid, the `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true, and so it works.


If you want to Authorize a user based on certain claims present in the token, your request will fail for either Jwt or AzureAd, depending on which one is able to authenticate first. That's where you would need to utilize multiple schemes so that the claims are correctly extracted for the selected scheme. The claims are usually different for Jwt and AzureAd.

Comment: If you are only interested in Authenticating a user and Authorize the request based on if user is Authenticated or not, then your approach should work. In other cases, it would definitely fail. There are scenarios where you have multiple endpoints, and you would want to Authorize that endpoint based on some custom Authorization policy and only if the token is AzureAd token for example, that's where you would need to utilise the schemes.

Comment: Also please take a look at an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38714) that was posted on GitHub for the similar scenario. The [suggestion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38714#issuecomment-990032860) was to use policy schemes.

Comment: I believe all of that would be true, if it weren't for the fact that I load and determine the necessary claims from our database. So we don't rely on claims from external providers. I tried to add multiple schemes and it worked as well, so we could consider this in the future. For the time being, I don't see the need to overcomplicate matters. Good to know there are alternatives. And as Rick Strahl said himself in his blog post, it all makes sense once you've figured it out.

Comment: Great, I am glad that it worked for you. Please feel free to contact if you need any help in future. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use this custom `JwtAuthMiddleware` and define the custom `ClaimsPrincipal` like that. The problem is that you are just extracting the claims from the token. Setting the `ClaimsPrincipal` like that wouldn't automatically authenticate the user i.e. `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` would be false. Hence you get 401.

The token needs to be validated. You are already using `AddJwtBearer` which you can customize the code like below if you haven't done that.

JWT bearer authentication performs authentication automatically by extracting and validating a JWT token from the Authorization request header. However, you need to set the [TokenValidationParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters?view=azure-dotnet) which tells the handler what to validate.

```
services
.AddAuthentication()
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{
    // you don't have to validate all of the parameters below
    // but whatever you need to, but see the documentation for more details
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = config.JwtToken.Issuer, // presuming config is your appsettings
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = config.JwtToken.Audience,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config.JwtToken.SigningKey))
    };
})
```

However, there is a caveat. When combining multiple authentication mechanisms, you need to utilise multiple authentication schemes. They play a role in defining the logic to select the correct authentication mechanism. That is because you can call `AddJwtBearer` or `AddCookie` multiple times for different scenarios. If the scheme name is not passed, it would try to utilize the default scheme and the authentication will fail, as it would have no way of knowing which mechanism to use JWT or AzureAd as they both use the Bearer token.

You mentioned that JWT works when `FallbackPolicy` is not set but you get 401 otherwise. That is because your authorization policy requires a user to be authenticated. The user was never authenticated as I mentioned in the beginning. If `FallbackPolicy` is not set it would work in the context of JWT being passed in the alright, but there is no requirement to check e.g user is authenticated and has a specific claim or role, so it works.

You would need to define an authentication policy scheme and set the [ForwardDefaultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationschemeoptions.forwarddefaultselector?view=aspnetcore-7.0) property of the [PolicySchemeOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.policyschemeoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0). `ForwardDefaultSecltor` is used to select a default scheme for the current request that authentication handlers should forward all authentication operations to by default.

So basically you need to set the `ForwardDefaultSecltor` delegate which uses some logic to forward the request to the correct scheme to handle the authentication.

So the above code would change to:

```
// scheme names below can be any string you like
services
    .AddAuthentication("MultiAuth") // virtual scheme that has logic to delegate
    .AddGitHub(GitHubAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, /*config*/) // uses GitHub scheme
    .AddAzureAd("AzureAd", /*config*/) // uses AzureAd scheme
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, /*config*/) // uses Cookies scheme
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { // above code for AddJwtBearer }) // uses Bearer scheme

    // this is quite important to use the same virtual scheme name below
    // which was used in the authentication call.
    .AddPolicyScheme("MultiAuth", null, options =>
    {
        // runs on each request should return the exact scheme name defined above
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
        {
            // if the authorization header is present, use the Bearer scheme
            string authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer "))
            {
                return "Bearer";
            }

            // custom logic for GitHub
            ...
            return GitHubAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            // custom logic for AzureAd
            ...
            return "AzureAd";

            // otherwise fallback to Cookies or whichever is the default authentication scheme
            return CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        };
    });
```

That way, you just remove the `JwtAuthMiddleware`. `AddJwtBearer` would automatically add the claims in the Claims object when the token is validated, which you can then use to define custom authorization policies to authorize the user.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This looks like the approach that Rick Strahl wrote about. I don't understand enough of authentication schemes to feel confident making the decision to go this way. Part of your analysis is correct, as I mention in the answer to my own question. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Mar/29/Combining-Bearer-Token-and-Cookie-Auth-in-ASPNET

Comment: @hbulens wow, if Rick Strahl had posted this a month before, I would have definitely found out. As I was implementing multiple authentication mechanism back in early Feb 2022. However, this approach is well documented  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes)  and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/policyschemes?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

So: some clients will be sending a cookie, and some will be sending `Authorize` header with a bearer token.

These are *authentication schemes* that you set up with `AddAuthentication`.

After that you need to set up *authorization* (`AddAuthorization`) to grant access to users who are *authentication* with either of these schemes.

(*Authentication* means checking that you are who you say you are (users), *authorization* means what you are and aren't allowed to do (roles) -- it's confusing.)